# log in with python requests failed

Tags: python-requests, python-3.6

I am trying to use requests to mimic a login for https://www.recreation.gov/. To do that, I first find out the request details by using chrome inspect, which is the following:

```
Request URL: https://www.recreation.gov/api/accounts/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 1.2.3.4
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

request header:
:authority: www.recreation.gov
:method: POST
:path: /api/accounts/login
:scheme: https
:accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
:accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
:accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
:cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
:content-length: 70
:content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
:cookie: alongcookie
:origin: https://www.recreation.gov
:pragma: no-cache
:referer: https://www.recreation.gov/
:sec-fetch-mode: cors
:sec-fetch-site: same-origin
:user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36


request payload:
{'username': 'myusername', 'password': 'mypassword'}
```

Here is my code:

```
headers = {
  "authority": "www.recreation.gov",
  "method":"POST",
  "scheme": "https",
  "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
  "content-length": "70",
  "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  "origin": "https://www.recreation.gov",
  "referer":"https://www.recreation.gov/",
  "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
  "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
  s.headers = headers
  url = 'https://www.recreation.gov/api/accounts/login'
  payload = {'username': 'myusername', 'password': 'mypassword'}
  response = s.post(url, data=payload)
  print(response)
```

But I always got:

## 403 Forbidden

\nRequest forbidden by administrative rules.\n

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for those headers? Looks like request forgery to me

Comment: I have no knowledge of the headers. These headers are retrieved from chrome inspect.

Comment: Ah, I see. Don't send those headers then, that's likely what's causing it to throw 403. It's seeing its own domain as a referrer/origin.

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on [basic auth](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/) with requests

Comment: Use `json` parameter instead of `data` while sending `payload` in your `POST` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the request header:

```
:content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

which means your request body should be encoded as JSON.

So change

```py
response = s.post(url, data=payload)
```

to:

```py
response = s.post(url, json=payload)
```